# Flask Tutorial - "Attribute Error"

Tags: python, flask

I am a newbie - just reached the end of Learn Python the Hard Way and am now trying my hand at Flask. I started with the official tutorial at the Flask website, but am getting stuck at [this step](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/dbinit/#tutorial-dbinit):

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash
from contextlib import closing

DATABASE = 'tmp/flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS',silent=True)

def connect_db():
        return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open.resource('schema.sql') as f:
            db.cursor.executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

At the Python Shell, if I do

```
from flaskr import init_db
init_db()
```

I see: `Attribute Error: Flask object has no attribute 'open' (in the line containing app.open.resource in init_db)`. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
app.open.resource
```

The example code:

```
app.open_resource
```

Can you spot the difference? In case you can't, the example code uses an underscore where you use a dot. A Flask object has no attribute called `open`, but it does have a method called [`open_resource`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.open_resource).